# Why `**/*ant*` exclude pattern doesn't work, but `"**/*ant*/**` works fine?

Tags: ant, fileset

Let's say I have this in one of my targets:

```
<path id="files">
   <fileset dir="${env.DIRECTORY}" casesensitive="false">
     <include name="**/*.html"/>
     <exclude name="**/*ant*"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

I'd like to group all the html files, except the ones containing the string ant. The way I wrote it above, it does not work. I also tried specifying the exclude like this:

```
<exclude name="*ant*"/>
```

Please notice that the fileset has it's case sensitiveness turned off. However, if I write:

```
<exclude name="**/*ant*/**"/>
```

This does work. Why don't the first and second versions of exclude work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and second case don't match because you are searching for directory name containing *ant*

Third case matches all files that have a ant element in their path, **including ant as a filename**.

You can also refer this [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#directorybasedtasks) documentation

Comment: Yes. It does not exclude the files containing ant.

Comment: Edited as per your response. Sorry for recommending hit n trial solution earlier :(